# Android Recyclerview in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I know it is not a good approach, but I have a layout with similar structure:

```
ScrollView
RelativeLayout (with TabLayout,textViews, ImageViews etc)
RecyclerView
RelativeLayout (with textViews, ImageViews etc)
```

The recyclerView part is dynamic, so it may have 1 TextView with ImageView, but it can have max. 4-5 lines of elements.

This is working fine, but when there are more items in recyclerView, then that section starts to scroll.

That's what I want to disable.

My RecyclerView part:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
```

I added to the RecyclerView this line:

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

So now the scrolling is disabled for that section, but now I don't see all items in RecyclerView.

How can I disable scrolling and keep the full height to see all the content there?

Comment: How about a `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: Not sure how and where to use NestedScrollView, because if I replace ScrollView with NestedScrollView it says can't resolve class NestedScrollView

Comment: The full class path is `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: Replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` and give that a try.  Is there a way to move the entire layout into a single RecyclerView implementation?

Comment: Thank you guys, using androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView did the trick. Of course a better approach is to move the entire layout to RecyclerView as @DMP suggested, but will consider it later, for now this solved my issue. Thank you, I think you can post it as an answer